# Add css class to all li parent elements in the ul with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html code like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
    <li class="should be = col-sm-4">
        <ul>
            <li class="should be = dropdown-header">Item0</li>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="should be = col-sm-4">
        <ul>
            <li class="should be = dropdown-header">Item0</li>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="should be = col-sm-4">
        <ul>
            <li class="should be = dropdown-header">Item0</li>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this code is generated from server side, now my question is, how can I append `col-sm-4` css class to all `li` parents and add css class `dropdown-header` to first `li` child elements with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Vanilla Javascript Solution:

By storing all applicable list items in a variable, that can be later ustilised in a `for` loop, we can iterate through each instance and add the required class.

This solution is preferable if an entire javascript library or framework (like jQuery) is not required for trivial change that only needs to occur once.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
// Get direct descendant list-item children using querySelectorAll and CSS child combinator selector 
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu > li');

// Add class to each instance in for loop
for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  listItems[i].className = 'col-sm-4';
}

// Get first list-item child of nested ul element with class name "col-sm-4" using querySelectorAll and CSS :first-child pseudo-selector  
var headerListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu .col-sm-4 li:first-child');

// Add class to each instance in for loop
for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  headerListItems[i].className = 'dropdown-header';
}

// Note: "querySelectorAll" allows for the ability to specify selectors using CSS Selector Syntax
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
    <li >
        <ul>
            <li>Item0</li>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li >
        <ul>
            <li >Item0</li>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li >
        <ul>
            <li >Item0</li>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### jQuery Solution:

Consider using the `.addClass()` method to add the required classes by specifying the intended selectors as demonstrated in the embedded code snippet below.

This solution is preferable if this change needs to occur more than once or elsewhere in a similar scope.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
jQuery('.dropdown-menu > li').addClass('col-sm-4');

jQuery('.dropdown-menu .col-sm-4 li:first-child').addClass('dropdown-header');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
    <li >
        <ul>
            <li>Item0</li>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li >
        <ul>
            <li >Item0</li>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li >
        <ul>
            <li >Item0</li>
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### Alternative: Standard CSS Selector Syntax

The elements in question can still be targeted using CSS Selector Syntax with the following methods:

For what would be *"col-sm-4"*: `.dropdown-menu > li`
Selecting the first direct descendant list-item element using the *child combinator* (`>`)

For what would be *"dropdown-header"*: `.dropdown-menu ul li:first-child`
Selecting the first child list-item element using `:first-child` *pseudo-selector*